# CloudFront -> S3 for static or API Gateway with multiple dynamic backends in ECS

Tags: aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy, amazon-ecs, http-redirect, aws-lambda-edge

I need to implement a reverse proxy/redirect service for site which will be hosted in AWS S3 (static JS assets) + CloudFront and multiple backends running as different tasks AWS ECS available at `domain.com/api/session_number` Redirect or reverse proxy service should analyze input parameter and redirect to corresponding backend.

So far I've found [ECS-nginx-proxy](https://github.com/codesuki/ecs-nginx-proxy) but it looks more like the tool for dev/stage environments. How such service can be implemented for production using AWS services like ALB + API Gateway, Lambda@Edge?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nginx, what you really want to put there is the Traefik Load Balancer:

1. [How should I setup Traefik on ECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292051/how-should-i-setup-traefik-on-ecs)
2. https://netbears.com/blog/traefik-cluster-ecs/

Comment: thank you for suggestion @shariqmaws, my initial idea was to run dynamic backends as one-off tasks, and as far as I understood, I should create new task definition, with corresponding docker labels for traefik. But I want to use one task definition and change only env vars, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

we've implemented a temporary solution with Traefik 1.7 and provisioning  frontend/backend configuration using Traefik REST API

so basically on each configuration change, there is a Traefik config update with POST call to `api/providers/rest`

such solution lacks HA support and on Traefik restart it's REST config is empty should be replaced with ALB-based solution probably